# Pi-hole software questions

Tags: discussion

Are Pi-hole based questions be allowed on site? Pi-hole software is not "really" a pi based software but it is usually used on a Pi.

Answer (score 9):

While it's not necessary to run Pi-hole on an RPi, it's certainly marketed as a projected intended for them. I think marking it off topic would do nothing but allienate and confuse new users.